# Reading emoji from database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a project with PHP/MYSQL. How do i store emojis in my database and read without alteration from PHP ?

My tables character set and collate are

`CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

Comment: Make sure you are [UTF-8 *all* the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) - particularly in your output.

Comment: If the DB has the correct value the storage is unrelated. How are you doing the select, is the encoding set on the connection there?

Comment: Thank you man setting character set in connection worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found the solution. Character set should be defined in database connection too.